# PyCharm Importing Error (chatterbot / Flask)

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm currently learning to program a chatbot but I faced an import error while running the program.
here's the error I got:
[image]

I already installed the packages:
[image]

I have no idea why this error arose nor how to fix it, I hope you can help.

Comment: Is that the right version of `ChatterBot`, in your stacktrace it's not struggling to find `ChatterBot` it can't find `storage` within `ChatterBot`.  Did they potentially move (or remove) that?

Also might help to verify your install if you just do a `import chatterbot` in a python terminal to see what comes back

Comment: @sedavidw when I install it using terminal i got this error (ERROR: chatterbot 1.0.5 has requirement pyyaml<5.2,>=5.1, but you'll have pyyaml 3.13 which is incompatible.
)

Comment: Did you mean import using a terminal?  If so...sounds like you need to upgrade your `pyyaml` install then.

Comment: yes. I'll try to upgrade and let you know.

Comment: @sedavidw The error above still the same (Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:), even though I upgraded pyyaml

Comment: Did you reinstall the chatterbot module?  I would recommend starting on a fresh python environment and doing clean installs

Answer (score 0):

Try to use flask version 1.0.0